# How to Dapper & AseClient

Tags: dapper

Unable to connect to Sybase, not getting error.

I have referenced `Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll` from `C:\Sybase\DataAccess\ADONET\dll` to my MVC 5 project, running in .NET 4.5

Web.Config Connections string

```
    <add name="MyASEServer" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.20:12000;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=USer1;Password=Password1;"
```

providerName="Sybase.Data.AseClient"/>

My code

```
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyASEServer"].ConnectionString;
    IDbConnection aseDB = new AseConnection(constr );
    var myCustomer = aseDB.Query<Customer>("select * fromdbo.customer");
```

When the debugger reaches `aseDB.Query....`,  it never return and not receiving any error.

What am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `Application Insights` is on in visual studio and all the exceptions are captured in it. So the application screen is not showing the exception.